# Computing Matrix-vector product between submatrices of multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array `A` of shape `(1000, 54, 50)` and another array `x` of shape `(1000, 54)`. For every `i=0, ..., 999` I. would like to compute `A[i, :, :] @ (A[i, :,:].T @ x[i])`.  What is the fastest way that leverages NumPy's vectorisation capabilities?

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randn(1000, 54, 50)
x = np.random.randn(1000, 54)

def slow_method(A, x):
    B = np.zeros((1000, 54))
    for i in range(1000):
        B[i] = A[i] @ (A[i].T @ x[i])
    return B
```

Another method I came up with is with `einsum` but it seems like it does a lot of redundant calculations.

```
def einsum_method(A, x)
    return np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij', A, np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij', np.transpose(A, axes=(0, 2, 1)), x))
```

Comment: `np.einsum('ijk,ilk,il->ij', A, A, x, optimize=['einsum_path', (1, 2), (0, 1)]).reshape(1000, 54, 1)`

Answer (score 2):

Main thing is that matmul treats N-D matrices as stacks of 2D matrices. Since x is already 2-D, we need to broadcast an additional dimension at the end to treat it as a stack of 54x1 "matrices". The reshape at the end is to flatten that dimension.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randn(1000, 54, 50)
x = np.random.randn(1000, 54)

result = A @ A.transpose((0, 2, 1)) @ x[:, :, None]

result = result.reshape((A.shape[0:2]))
```

Note:

`A[i] @ (A[i].T @ x[i])` and `A[i] @ A[i].T @ x[i]` will give nearly identical but different answers. Wanted to mention this since I ran into this while verifying my answer.